# float left span and div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, css-float

I have this problem:
http://liberainformazione.it/

[image]

Title css rule:

```
p.right_sidebar_title {
font-size: 16px!important;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
margin: 7px 0!important;
line-height: 18px!important;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
width: 300px;
}
```

Blue rectangle css rule:

```
.post-category-rightSidebar {
background: #369;
display: inline;
float: left;
font-size: 10px;
height: 16px;
line-height: 17px;
margin-right: 5px;
padding: 0 5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: white;
}
```

In Chrome or Firefox the blue rectangle is near the title but with IE the title is on new line.....
I haven't understand why IE not recognize my css rules.

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page has `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`, so IE9 is operating as IE7.

In IE7, specifying `width` or (`height`) value triggers so called `hasLayout` which makes element's box somewhat isolated and prevents its contents from being floated by any external elements.

You should either set `X-UA-Compatible` meta element to [`IE=edge`](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2009/07/disable-ie8-compatibility-mode/) value (best option), or remove `width: 300px;` from `p.right_sidebar_title` rule, or specify this width for a container that contains *both* `p.right_sidebar_title` element *and* floating color square.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you don't have a float on `p.right_sidebar_title`, try adding `float: left;` to that.

If it helps, I'd put `p.right_sidebar_title` and `.post-category-rightSidebar` inside their own div:

```
<div>
    <div class="post-category-rightSidebar"></div>
    <p class="right_sidebar_title">Title</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!